# Запуск .py файла из кода

Tags: python

Возможно ли реализовать запуск файла с .py или .exe расширением из кода?

Например:

```
foo = 1

if foo == 1:
    запускаем файл
```

Comment: а обычный импорт для .ру вам не подойдёт ?

Comment: @Интик, ну экзешник не импортнуть никак)

Comment: @Extend так в вопросе .ру тоже написан. и доставая свой хрустальный шар, предпологаю что изначально есть скрипт на питоне из которого делают ехе и патом незнают как запустить. и вариант с импортом сильно всё упрощает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть множество вариантов это сделать.
Вот 3 примера.
.exe файл (только для Windows)

```
import os 
foo = 1

if foo == 1:
    os.startfile('Programm.exe')
```

.py файлы

```
import subprocess 

foo = 1

if foo == 1:
    subprocess.Popen("python3", "script.py")
```

или же

```
import os

foo = 1

if foo == 1:
    os.system("python [script]")
```

Первый вариант открывает .exe файл.
Второй открывает .py файл в отдельном процессе, с которым можно взаимодействовать модулем subprocess.
Третий вариант отправляет команду в консоль для открытия файла.

Comment: Вот это мне больше нравится, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот один из вариантов:

```
os.startfile('Programm.exe')
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное